# Array data send and save nicely to table, but error message show

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

a'm try to save array data to mysql table, the data something like this

001/TK/2014|10,011/TK/2014|20,017/TK/2014|30,006/TK/2014|40,019/TK/2014|50,

first i try to explode the data with this code

```
$array = explode(",",POST['data']);
```

secondly i use looping code to split beetwen Id|value  than the output something like this :

```
Array ( [0] => 001/TK/2014 [1] => 10 )
```

this's looping code and saving to the table :

```
foreach($array as $r){
 $result = explode("|", $r);  
  if(!empty($result)){
$cn->insertRows("tdesa","IdDesa,IdKat,Jumlah,Ket,tahun",
"'$kode','$result[0]',$result[1],'test','$today'");
}}
```

the data was saved nicely, but why showing the error message like : 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test','2014')' at line 1
INSERT INTO tdesa(IdDesa,IdKat,Jumlah,Ket,tahun) VALUES ('0002/DESA/2014','',,'test','2014')

and why sql read this ('0002/DESA/2014','',,'test','2014') but the table save & have that value ?

can anyone help me ??

Comment: You have to put single quote on $result[1] like `'$result[1]'` in insert query

Comment: also try with escape your inserting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, first remove last comma

```
$data = '001/TK/2014|10,011/TK/2014|20,017/TK/2014|30,006/TK/2014|40,019/TK/2014|50,';
$data = rtrim($data,',');

$array = explode(",", $data);
```